# error is coming lib-faac-dev not found

Tags: audio, ubuntu, ffmpeg

i installed faac from here http://sourceforge.net/projects/faac/files/faac-src/faac-1.28/faac-1.28.tar.gz/
and then m running this command which is giving me this error  basicall i want to install ffmpeg with audio conversion for libmp3lame , means with audio conversion.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential subversion git-core checkinstall yasm texi2html libfaac-dev libjack-jackd2-dev libmp3lame-dev libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev libsdl1.2-dev libtheora-dev libvorbis-dev libvpx-dev libx11-dev libxfixes-dev libxvidcore-dev zlib1g-dev

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libfaac-dev
```

following this article 
http://pasindudps.blogspot.com/2010/12/compiling-ffmpeg-in-ubuntu-1010.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added the multiverse to the main repositories in /etc/apt/sources.list and was able to install libfaac-dev.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu natty main restricted universe multiverse